# Android SQLite error when creating a table (VARCHAR is causing an error)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, varchar

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Practice", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah (subjects VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR, amount VARCHAR");
}
```

The error log:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "VARCHAR": syntax error 06-30 23:46:21.834
>   11420-11420/com.asd.sqltesting D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   06-30 23:46:21.835 11420-11420/com.asd.sqltesting E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.asd.sqltesting, PID: 11420
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.asd.sqltesting/com.asd.sqltesting.MainActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VARCHAR": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah (subjects
>   VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR, amount VARCHAR
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VARCHAR":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   blah (subjects VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR, amount VARCHAR
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
>                                                                                      at com.asd.sqltesting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

I tried to create a table with multiple columns but this keeps happening. This exact line of code is used for another project but the error occurs the second time I use it in the same activity.

Comment: wow that was stupid.. but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the closing ')':

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah (subjects VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR, amount VARCHAR);");
```

The size of the VARCHAR is optional in sqlite

[image]

see https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/type-name.html.

To verify your statement you can use `sqlite3`

```
$ sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah (subjects VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR, amount VARCHAR);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a round bracket.

**Write your query like this :**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah (subjects VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR, amount VARCHAR)");
```

> Insert a `)` after `amount VARCHAR`

**EDIT : 1**

> **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException : (1) near "VARCHAR": syntax error**
>
> Your logcat is displaying this Exception. So generally this exception
>   arises whenever you are missing some character like `,` or `"` or in
>   your case it is `)`. Observe your query you will find **two** opening
>   round brackets `(`, One before **Create table** & 2nd after **blah**.
>   But there is only **one** closing bracket `)` at the end. This is the
>   reason i have suggested you to add one `)` after `amount VARCHAR`.

Comment: `VARCHAR` is perfectly valid in sqlite and such columns get the `TEXT` default affinity.

Comment: I think it is not default.. If i m wrong correct me @laalto

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_3 "If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity."

Comment: So do i have to change my sentence to "TEXT is a recommended type not required" ?? @laalto

Answer (score 1):

`sql` query is wrong.

Correct it first

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah (subjects VARCHAR(size), notes VARCHAR(size), amount VARCHAR(size))");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query is wrong , you missed the closing ')': 
Dont create Database in MainActicity directly , follow below approach and call database always via Async Task,

Best practice to use SQLiteOpenHelper , refer below bolg

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper

Sample project

- http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-persist-data-on-android-with-sqlite/
- http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/02/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-sqlite.html

Create table like below ,

Sample:

```
String CREATE_POSTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_POSTS +
            "(" +
                KEY_POST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + // Define a primary key
                KEY_POST_USER_ID_FK + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TABLE_USERS + "," + // Define a foreign key
                KEY_POST_TEXT + " TEXT" +
            ")";

String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS +
        "(" +
            KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT," +
            KEY_USER_PROFILE_PICTURE_URL + " TEXT" +
        ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_POSTS_TABLE);
db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
```